# I have deployed the build folder inside wwwroot folder using ftp. But still my web url is running it's default page

Tags: azure, deployment, create-react-app

I have deployed the create-react-app build folder inside site/wwwroot/ folder using ftp in Azure. But still my web url is running azure's default page

I have created the build using npm run build command

So how can I deplot my static create-react-app on Azure ?

My package.json file is -

```
{
  "name": "yoke",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "config": "^3.1.0",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "serve": "^11.0.2"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `"homepage": "https://your_domain/directory_name/",` to your `package.json` file.

Comment: I did the same thing still not working

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried to do the same (I assume you've used an Azure App Service) and it works fine. Ensure that you have the contents of your build folder in the wwwroot folder itself by following this set of documentation:
[create-react-app in Azure App Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AjTi.png)

**Edit:**
It looks like your in case (Node Web App) you should set the default document as described in this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#NodeHome.

Put the *index.js* file in the wwwroot with the following contents:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var options = {
    index: 'index.html'
};
server.use('/', express.static('/home/site/wwwroot', options));
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

**Edit2 (the part, omitted from the MS article):**
Then in your app's blade in Azure Portal open Advanced Tools and click "Go", Kudu web page will open. Click the "Bash" link in the top menu and run the following commands in the console:

```
npm install express
```

After the packages have been successfully installed, go to the Overview blade in the portal and restart your app service.

Comment: yes I have the same directory as yours. Still not working

Comment: What's your Web App's operating system and runtime stack?

Comment: My OS is ubuntu and runtime stack is Node LTS

Comment: Edited my initial answer.

Comment: Followed your steps..  created index.js with the above content, still not working

Comment: Have you restarted your app service after placing index.js?

Comment: I changed it from FTP to github build now, still it is not working

Comment: I never cease to amaze how knowledge becomes obsolete. Edited my answer once again. This time tested the solution myself :)

Comment: After following your steps a new has occurred as follows : 
:( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

Can't find module express is showing on application error log

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as accepted then? It would help people with the same question and I'll earn some reputation. Thanks.